# Filter several dataframes based on common dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have 21 dataframes. Each dataframe has one column that are dates. What I want to do is filter all of these dataframes based on dates that are common to every dataframe. Here is an example of the dataframe:

[image]

Now image 20 other similar dataframes and I want to filter them all, in order for all the dataframes to have only data of dates that are common to every dataframe. So every dataframe will have the same length and the same dates.

I only managed to filter based on the shortest dataframe (the one with the least amount of dates), but that didn't work because there are dates that are not in some dataframes resulting in different length dataframes. (I used the `.isin()` method)

Comment: Would a merge/concat work for what you are trying to do? Or do you need to keep them separate?

Comment: I need them separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1 - Take 1 data frame and store all its dates

```
# numpy array
import numpy as np
dateList = df1["date"].values;
```

#### Step 2 - process dates ofother dataframe

```
# make a list of name of all data frame
dataFrameList = [df2, df3, .......df21]

# processing - geting all common dates in 21 df
for df in dataFrameList:
    # dates of current dataframe
    dfdatelist = df["date"].values
    # take intersection
    dateList = np.intersect1d(dateList, dfdatelist)
```

#### Step 3 - Filtering  all dataframe on common dates

```
df1 = df1 [dataframe["dates"].values.tolist() in dateList.tolist()]

for df in dataFrameList:
    df = df [dataframe["dates"].values.tolist() in dateList.tolist()]

# Print result
print(df1)

for df in dataFrameList:
    print(df);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was able to generalize it even more by using the functools.reduce that I found here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html

Comment: In Step 3 what is dataframe['dates'] referring to? It wasn't previously defined.